# In WCF, does a timeout fault the channel?

Tags: wcf, timeoutexception

In WCF, does a timeout on a request-response operation fault the channel at the client's end?

If a server times out when sending a response, is the channel faulted at the server's end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a timeout will fault the channel - and there's always only *one* channel linking a client and a server - the server doesn't have a channel of its own...

You basically have:

```
+-----------+                       +-----------+
|           |_______________________|           |
|  Client   |     The Channel       |  Server   |
|           |-----------------------|           |
+-----------+                       +-----------+
```

There's really only *one channel* which connects the two bits. As for timeouts - if both ends define a different value for the same timeout, the smaller value will "win" and become relevant - the higher value (on the other end) isn't taken into account.

Comment: Perhaps it's just how I've expressed it, but I meant from the perspective of each system. If a timeout is experienced from either end of the channel, will the channel be faulted for the "timed out" party in both cases?

Comment: yes - the smaller values for each timeout will "win" - if you have 100 years timeout on your client, but your server is set to 5 seconds - the channel between the two will fault after 5 seconds.

Comment: Your ASCII art is hideous, yet enlightening. Thanks.

Comment: @marc_s, Are there any instances when a timeout would not fault the channel?  I'm not seeing this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13402977/546561

Answer (score 1):

Correct, the timeout will fault the channel. You can set the max timeout time on both the client and the server side.

Comment: and the smaller of the two values will "win"

Answer (score 0):

It depends which Timeout.

If you hit the `SendTimeout` or `ReceiveTimeout` of your binding (in my case `NetTcpBinding`), then yes, the channel will fault.

BUT, if you hit the `OperationTimeout` of your Service (in my case DuplexChannel) then you will just get a `TimeoutException` and the channel will **NOT** fault.